# Encode object to JSON and encrypt with AES (with tests)

Tags: json, cryptography, go, aes

While the task at hand is relatively straightforward, it turned out AES in Go is a bit clunky so I was wondering if this seems right. Also, any tips on Go coding in general are more than welcome.

```
// Package aesjson provides a function to encode an object to JSON and apply
// AES encryption to it.
package aesjson

import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "crypto/rand"
    "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/json"
    "io"
    "log"
)

const (
    aesKey = "U3RhY2tPdmVyZmxvdyBmb3IgdGhlIHdpbiEgICAgICA="
)

var (
    aesCipher cipher.Block
)

func init() {
    aesKeyDecoded, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(aesKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    aesCipher, err = aes.NewCipher(aesKeyDecoded)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}

func spaces(c int) []byte {
    return bytes.Repeat([]byte(" "), c)
}

// EncodeJSON encodes the given object to JSON (via json.Marshal) and then
// encrypts it using the AES encryption algorithm.
// It returns the base64 of the encrypted JSON with the IV prepended to it.
func EncodeJSON(val interface{}) (string, error) {
    valjs, err := json.Marshal(val)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    paddingLen := 16 - len(valjs)%16
    text := append(valjs, spaces(paddingLen)...)

    ciphertext := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize+len(text))
    iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]
    if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv); err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    mode := cipher.NewCBCEncrypter(aesCipher, iv)
    mode.CryptBlocks(ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:], text)
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(ciphertext), nil
}
```

And this is my test file - really interested if this is the right approach to testing a function like this.

```
package aesjson_test

import (
    crand "crypto/rand"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "testing"

    "projectfolder/aesjson"
)

func init() {
    // Remove randomness
    crand.Reader = rand.New(rand.NewSource(1))

    log.Println("Randomness disabled!")
}

func TestEncode(t *testing.T) {
    input := &aesjson.Token{
        ID: "1234567890-1234567890",
    }
    want := "Uv38ByGCZU8WP18PmmIdcprw1O0tpU/WBGgDIBYBpYaoJ2Lay7VnJGhKzswMb7ndHORd4kaege0cnsKkHMogTA=="

    got, err := aesjson.EncodeJSON(input)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("failed with error: %v", err)
    }

    if got != want {
        t.Errorf("want: %q\ngot: %q", want, got)
    }
}
```

Comment: There are mode implementations that can add padding automatically. Not sure if you did it manually for a specific reason? I recommend this talk from gophercon 2016: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2r_KMzXB74w&index=20&list=PL2ntRZ1ySWBdliXelGAItjzTMxy2WQh0P

Comment: Interesting video - I am, however, limited by the decryption code, which uses a very limited library (that only supports CBC for example) and I'm padding with spaces to keep it valid JSON. That said, could you clarify which mode you're referring to? The [BlockMode](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/cipher/#BlockMode) interface specifically states that "the length of src must be a multiple of the block size".

Comment: GCM can encrypt streams of blocks and adds padding IIRC. This miight be informative, although it sparsely mentions GCM: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220751/how-to-choose-an-aes-encryption-mode-cbc-ecb-ctr-ocb-cfb#1220869